# Enabling gzip compression in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, compression, gzip

I am trying to enable Gzip compression as per the Google pagespeed suggestions as to how to get my site to load faster.

I have tried the suggested addition to my .htaccess file as found on https://varvy.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html but it does not work correctly.

My current .htaccess file contains the following code. The rewrite rule works correctly as does the caching of the various file types. I am not experienced in working with the .htaccess file, so excuse me if I have made an obvious error. I have tried reading around the issue but can't seem to find the answer I need.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access 1 month"
 ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
 </IfModule>
 ## EXPIRES CACHING ##

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz|html|htm)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
 mod_gzip_on Yes
 mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
 mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
 mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
 mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
 mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
 </ifModule>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like I needed mod_deflate instead of mod_gzip.

Added the following to my .htaccess file and it now compresses files correctly:

```
 <FilesMatch "\.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
 </FilesMatch>
```